# Printing a specific number pattern as below in java

Tags: java

I am a newbie to java programming and was trying to achieve the following number pattern to be printed.
It is a square matrix based on the input received from user and the matrix is going to be like below;(First n numbers in top line and next n numbers in bottom most line, now again next n numbers in 2nd line and next n numbers in last but one line and so on....)

```
If n=3;
1 2 3
7 8 9
4 5 6

If n=4;
1 2 3 4
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 
5 6 7 8
```

Though i feel everything is alright, there is an error during execution - *java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:* thrown. Can you please advise?

```
import java.util.*;

class TopBottomNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int s = 1, n;
        int a[][];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of rows to print the pattern: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();

        a = new int[n - 1][n - 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < (n / 2); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                a[i][j] = s;
                a[n - 1][j] = s + n;
                s++;
            }

            s = s + n;
        }

        if (n % 2 != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                a[n / 2][i] = s;
                s++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `new int[n-1][n-1];` why `n-1`? `n` is what you need here

Comment: Your line `int a[][] = new int[n-1][n-1];` makes an array that's just a little too small in both directions - each dimension can only range from `0` to `n-2`.

Comment: Previous 2 comments clarified: `new int[4]` allows indices 0, 1, 2, 3. _Which indeed is a bit baroque, seeing `[4]` but never allowed to use it._

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca thanks a lot. It is indeed n. Also for the pattern to work in the above code in the inner for loop `a[n-1][j]` should be replaced by `a[k]` where `k=n-1` and decrement k by 1 in the outer for loop. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you @DawoodibnKareem it makes sense to me now.

Comment: Thank you @JoopEggen I agree that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people have pointed out in the comments, the error is caused by this line:

```
a = new int[n - 1][n - 1];
```

This means that if the user introduces the number 4, you will a dimesion of 3 (0, 1, 2) oposed to the 4 you want (0, 1, 2, 3).

If you remove the -1